# The improved solution for 2 sum algorithm

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I try to work out the functional implementation for the algorithm in leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/#/description)

I guess what I need are 3 functions as followed:

- `List[Int] => List[(Int, Int)]` Zip the element with position
- `List[(Int, Int)], Int, Int => List[((Int, Int) , (Int, Int))]` Zip the element and position with rest of element and position and filter with Sum
- `List[((Int, Int) , (Int, Int))] => List[(Int, Int)]` Map to the position

The code looks like this:

```
  def findTwoSumElements(xs: List[Int], sum: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
    val zipWithIndex = xs.zipWithIndex
    var tailElements = zipWithIndex

    val result = zipWithIndex.map(t => {
      val element = zipAndFilter(tailElements, t, sum)
      tailElements = tailElements.tail
      element
     }
    )

    result.flatten.map(t => (t._1._2, t._2._2))
  }

  private def zipAndFilter(xs: List[(Int, Int)], x: (Int, Int), sum: Int): List[((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] = {
    xs.map(t => (t, x)).filter(t => (t._1._1 + t._2._1) == sum)
  }

 println(findTwoSumElements(List(1,2,3,4), 10)) //List()
 println(findTwoSumElements(List(1,2,3,4), 7)) //List((3,2))
 println(findTwoSumElements(List(1,2,3,4), 5)) //List((3,0), (2,1))
 println(findTwoSumElements(List(), 5)) //List()
```

I would like to improve this part of the code by not using `var`

```
  var tailElements = zipWithIndex

  val result = zipWithIndex.map(t => {
     val element = zipAndFilter(tailElements, t, sum)
     tailElements = tailElements.tail
     element
   }
  )
```

The reason is I want to remove duplicate Tuple[Int, Int], for example, it will return (x, y) and (y, x) together if I dont mutate the tail

Can I have some suggestion or demo code about how to improve it and also for the whole implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the simplified problem in which for each input would have exactly one solution, then you can write the solution as a one-liner:

```scala
def twoSum(nums: List[Int], target: Int): List[Int] =
  nums.combinations(2).find(_.sum == target).get.map(nums.indexOf)
```

Expanded solution, with explicit types:

```scala
def twoSum(nums: List[Int], target: Int): List[Int] = {
  val comb: Iterator[List[Int]] = nums.combinations(2) // Get 2-sized combinations iterator
  val find: Option[List[Int]] = comb.find(_.sum == target) // Find the first (and only) combination having sum equals to our target
  val res: List[Int] = find.get // Exactly one solution
  val idx: List[Int] = res.map(nums.indexOf) // Get the indexes in the original list
}
```

---

A alternative and generic solution, that allows multiple or no result at all (returns `List[List[Int]]`):

```scala
 def twoSum(nums: List[Int], target: Int): List[List[Int]] =
   nums.combinations(2).collect {
     case couple if couple.sum == target =>
       couple.map(nums.indexOf)
   }.toList
```

It can be generalized even more accepting combinations size (`2` in our example) as a parameter

Comment: Nice to know combinations !. Thanks a lot. It would be better to use filter rather than find, it may have more than one matched elements. Also, we can skip the usage of get, it may return `none` value.

Comment: The assignment explicitly states "exactly one solution". I'll update the answer with a generic solution.

Comment: one-line solution above is giving incorrect output, for twoSum(List(3,3), 6) it should result in List(0,1) as per leet code problem but its giving List(0,0)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I'll take a shot :)

How about the solution below:

```
  def twoSum(nums: Seq[Int], target: Int): Seq[Int] =
    nums.zipWithIndex.
      filter(x =>
        (nums.take(nums.indexOf(x._1)) ++ nums.drop(nums.indexOf(x._1)+1))
        .contains(target - x._1)).map(_._2)
```

Here's what being done (using array [2, 7, 11, 15] and target=9 as example):

1. We [zip with index](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-zip-zipwithindex-stream-examples) to get each number paired with its position, e.g. (2,0),(7,1)...
2. We filter each pair by the presence of its number difference with the target (i.e. target - number) in the original collection with itself removed (see the nums.[take](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_3.html) ++ nums.[drop](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_3.html))
3. We map each resulting pair to its position part (e.g. (2,0) => 0, (7,1) => 1)
4. The resulting sequence contains only the positions of the numbers that have corresponding sum-pairs that add to the target: (0,1).

Answer (score 2):

`combinations(2)` will always give you O(n^2) complexity. Leetcode will timeout your solution for large inputs.

The last `.map(nums.indexOf)` won't work since you will get a wrong answer for "[3, 3] seeking for 6".

One solution I would propose is

```scala
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
    import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap 
    def run(index: Int, map: HashMap[Int, Int]): Array[Int] = {
        val value = nums(index)
        map get (target - value) match {
            case Some(foundInd) => Array(foundInd, index)
            case None => run(index + 1, map + (value -> index))
        }
    }
    run(0, HashMap())
}
```

It is not really fancy but it runs in linear time, works for all test cases, and without mutation.

Answer (score 1):

Scala has a built-in [combinations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#combinations(n:Int):Iterator[Repr]) method that does a lot of the work for you.  This makes finding the target sum as easy as:

```
val result = nums.combinations(2).filter{case List(x, y) => x + y == target}.next
```

Then you can map the answer back to the indices by:

```
val indices = result map (nums.zipWithIndex.toMap)
```

Comment: Nice solution but what about if you get [3,3]? this would return [1,1] instead of [0,1]

Answer (score 0):

```
 def sol(inputArray: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {

    def recPass(list: List[(Int, Int)], map: Map[Int, Int]): Array[Int] = list match {
      case (elem, index) :: tail =>
        val complement = target - elem
        if (map.contains(complement)) Array(map(complement), index)
        else recPass(tail, map + (elem -> index))
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution")
    }
    recPass(inputArray.zipWithIndex.toList, Map.empty)
  }
```

or

```
  def sol(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
      def tailRec(map: Map[Int, Int], index: Int): Array[Int] = {

  if (index >= nums.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution") else {
    if (map.contains(nums(index))) {
      Array(map(nums(index)), index)
    } else {
      tailRec(map + (target - nums(index) -> index), index + 1)
    }
  }
}
  tailRec(Map(), 0)
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate as to why you've posted these answers. What are their advantages/disadvantages compared to the other answers posted 4 years ago.

Comment: Well, first, most of the answers above do not work for all the cases, as I have mentioned above in the comment,  second my solution doesn't use vars and is 89% efficient and less memory then all the other scala solutions on leet code.

Comment: Information worthy of inclusion in the posted answer instead of hidden in the comments.